# Rotate/Transform an Element with ThreeDubMedia Drag

Tags: javascript, jquery

Original Fiddle - http://liveweave.com/7dKduz
Drag/Resize/Rotate Fiddle - http://liveweave.com/4EW0Hy
Drag/Rotate(X&Y as well) - http://liveweave.com/E4MCh4

I'm working on an experiment on rotating elements using [ThreeDubMedia's Drag Plugin](http://threedubmedia.com/code/event/drag/)

[image]

There's a demo on ThreeDubMedia's website called [circular](http://threedubmedia.com/code/event/drag/demo/circular).

The sample element I'm trying to rotate it's width and height are different. Therefore radius won't work.

It's a nice demo however I'm not sure how to incorporate this interactive rotation into my experiment.

I came across [jquery.ui.rotatable.js](https://github.com/godswearhats/jquery-ui-rotatable) ([demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/ALASa/)) that does exactly what I'm trying to figure out. Except it's using the JQuery UI library, while I'm using [ThreeDubMedia's Drag Plugin](http://threedubmedia.com/code/event/drag/).

I've made/done 360 Rotations before ([360 Degree Angular Slider](http://codepen.io/mikethedj4/pen/IEnKu)) using [.each](http://api.jquery.com/each/) I been trying and trying to get it to work with this plugin but as soon as rotate is called and I use rotateX or rotateY after (same goes for scaling with other demos) main rotate gets called.

```
var FinalizeRotation = function() {
  if (($("#rotate").val() === "") && ($("#rotateX").val() === "")) {
    $("#rotateFinal").val($("#rotateY").val());
  } else if (($("#rotate").val() === "") && ($("#rotateY").val() === "")) {
    $("#rotateFinal").val($("#rotateX").val());
  } else if (($("#rotateX").val() === "") && ($("#rotateY").val() === "")) {
    $("#rotateFinal").val($("#rotate").val());
  } else if ($("#rotate").val() === "") {
    $("#rotateFinal").val($("#rotateX").val() + " " + $("#rotateY").val());
  } else if ($("#rotateX").val() === "") { 
    $("#rotateFinal").val($("#rotate").val() + " " + $("#rotateY").val());
  } else if ($("#rotateY").val() === "") {
    $("#rotateFinal").val($("#rotate").val() + " " + $("#rotateX").val());
  } else {
    $("#rotateFinal").val($("#rotate").val() + " " + $("#rotateX").val() + " " + $("#rotateY").val());
  }
};

// Handles Drag and RotateX & RotateY
$('.element').drag('start',function( ev, dd ){
  dd.attr = $( ev.target ).prop("className");
}).drag(function( ev, dd ) {
  var props = {};
  if ( dd.attr.indexOf("E") > -1 ){
    $("#rotateX").val("rotateX(" + Math.max( 32, ev.pageY ) + "deg)").change();
  }
  if ( dd.attr.indexOf("S") > -1 ){
    $("#rotateY").val("rotateY(" + Math.max( 32, ev.pageX ) + "deg)").change();
  }
  if ( dd.attr.indexOf("W") > -1 ){
    $("#rotateX").val("rotateX(" + Math.max( 32, ev.pageY ) + "deg)").change();
  }
  if ( dd.attr.indexOf("N") > -1 ){
    $("#rotateY").val("rotateY(" + Math.max( 32, ev.pageX ) + "deg)").change();
  }
  if ( dd.attr.indexOf("element") > -1 ){
    props.top = dd.offsetY;
    props.left = dd.offsetX;
  }
  $( this ).css( props );
});

// Rotate 360 Degrees 
$(".rotatable").on("mousedown touchstart", function() {
  $(".element").each(function() {
    var container = $(this),
        body = $(document),
        angler = container.find(".rotatable").parent();

    angler.on("mousedown touchstart", mouseDown);
    body.on("mouseup touchend", mouseUp);

    function setAngle(value) {
      $("#rotate").val("rotate("+ value +"deg)").change();
    }

    function mouseDown(event) {
      body.on("mousemove.rotatable", handleMove);
      body.on("touchmove.rotatable", handleMove);
      handleMove(event);
      event.preventDefault();
    }

    function mouseUp(event) {
      body.off("mousemove.rotatable", handleMove);
      body.off("touchmove.rotatable", handleMove);
    }

    function handleMove(event) {
      var mouseX = event.pageX;
      var mouseY = event.pageY;

      setAngle(0);
      var ofs = angler.offset();
      ofs.left += angler.height()/2;
      ofs.top += angler.width()/2;

      var x = mouseX - ofs.left;
      var y = mouseY - ofs.top;

      var angle = Math.atan2(x, y) * 180 / Math.PI;
      angle = 180 - angle;
      // strip decimal, go between 0-360
      angle = ((angle + 360) | 0) % 360;
      setAngle(angle);
    }
  });
});

// Finalize Rotation For Selected Element
$(".handlerotate").on('keyup change', function() {
    FinalizeRotation();
    $(".element").css("transform", $("#rotateFinal").val());
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Drag/Rotate/Resize = http://liveweave.com/ik8TB5
*(Includes My New RotateMe Plugin):* http://jsbin.com/zeguyipizizi/1/edit
Drag/Rotate/RotateX/RotateY = http://jsbin.com/dusacabobupa/1/edit
http://liveweave.com/vLYVUW

Drag/Rotate/Resize = http://liveweave.com/ik8TB5
Drag/Rotate/RotateX/RotateY = http://liveweave.com/vLYVUW

The only way I could figure out how to get it to work is by calling a variable `rotateable` and calling true/1 or false to enable/disable the rotation methods.

Not the best way to go about doing this, but I haven't figured out another way on getting this to work.

**Drag/Rotate/Resize**

```
var rotateable = false;

$('.element').drag('start',function( ev, dd ){
  dd.attr = $( ev.target ).prop("className");
  dd.width = $( this ).width();
  dd.height = $( this ).height();
}).drag(function( ev, dd ) {
  var props = {};
  if ( dd.attr.indexOf("E") > -1 ){
    props.width = Math.max( 32, dd.width + dd.deltaX );
  }
  if ( dd.attr.indexOf("S") > -1 ){
    props.height = Math.max( 32, dd.height + dd.deltaY );
  }
  if ( dd.attr.indexOf("W") > -1 ){
    props.width = Math.max( 32, dd.width - dd.deltaX );
    props.left = dd.originalX + dd.width - props.width;
  }
  if ( dd.attr.indexOf("N") > -1 ){
    props.height = Math.max( 32, dd.height - dd.deltaY );
    props.top = dd.originalY + dd.height - props.height;
  }
  if ( dd.attr.indexOf("element") > -1 ){
    props.top = dd.offsetY;
    props.left = dd.offsetX;
  }
  $( this ).css( props );
});

// Rotate 360 Degrees 
$(".rotatable").on("mousedown touchstart", function() {
  rotateable = 1;
  if (rotateable) {
    $(".element").each(function() {
      var container = $(this),
          body = $(document),
          angler = container.find(".rotatable").parent();

      angler.on("mousedown touchstart", mouseDown);
      body.on("mouseup touchend", mouseUp);

      function setAngle(value) {
        angler.css("transform", "rotate(" + value + "deg)").change();
      }

      function mouseDown(event) {
        body.on("mousemove.rotatable", handleMove);
        body.on("touchmove.rotatable", handleMove);
        handleMove(event);
        event.preventDefault();
      }

      function mouseUp(event) {
        body.off("mousemove.rotatable", handleMove);
        body.off("touchmove.rotatable", handleMove);
        rotateable = false;
      }

      function handleMove(event) {
        if (rotateable) {
          var mouseX = event.pageX;
          var mouseY = event.pageY;

          setAngle(0);
          var ofs = angler.offset();
          ofs.left += angler.height()/2;
          ofs.top += angler.width()/2;

          var x = mouseX - ofs.left;
          var y = mouseY - ofs.top;

          var angle = Math.atan2(x, y) * 180 / Math.PI;
          angle = 180 - angle;
          // strip decimal, go between 0-360
          angle = ((angle + 360) | 0) % 360;
          setAngle(angle);
        }
      }
    }); 
  }
});
```

**Drag/Rotate/RotateX/RotateY**

```
var FinalizeRotation = function() {
  if (($("#rotate").val() === "") && ($("#rotateX").val() === "")) {
    $("#rotateFinal").val($("#rotateY").val());
  } else if (($("#rotate").val() === "") && ($("#rotateY").val() === "")) {
    $("#rotateFinal").val($("#rotateX").val());
  } else if (($("#rotateX").val() === "") && ($("#rotateY").val() === "")) {
    $("#rotateFinal").val($("#rotate").val());
  } else if ($("#rotate").val() === "") {
    $("#rotateFinal").val($("#rotateX").val() + " " + $("#rotateY").val());
  } else if ($("#rotateX").val() === "") { 
    $("#rotateFinal").val($("#rotate").val() + " " + $("#rotateY").val());
  } else if ($("#rotateY").val() === "") {
    $("#rotateFinal").val($("#rotate").val() + " " + $("#rotateX").val());
  } else {
    $("#rotateFinal").val($("#rotate").val() + " " + $("#rotateX").val() + " " + $("#rotateY").val());
  }
};

// Handles Drag and RotateX & RotateY
$('.element').drag('start',function( ev, dd ){
  dd.attr = $( ev.target ).prop("className");
}).drag(function( ev, dd ) {
  var props = {};
  if ( dd.attr.indexOf("E") > -1 ){
    $("#rotateX").val("rotateX(" + Math.max( 32, ev.pageY ) + "deg)").change();
  }
  if ( dd.attr.indexOf("S") > -1 ){
    $("#rotateY").val("rotateY(" + Math.max( 32, ev.pageX ) + "deg)").change();
  }
  if ( dd.attr.indexOf("W") > -1 ){
    $("#rotateX").val("rotateX(" + Math.max( 32, ev.pageY ) + "deg)").change();
  }
  if ( dd.attr.indexOf("N") > -1 ){
    $("#rotateY").val("rotateY(" + Math.max( 32, ev.pageX ) + "deg)").change();
  }
  if ( dd.attr.indexOf("element") > -1 ){
    props.top = dd.offsetY;
    props.left = dd.offsetX;
  }
  $( this ).css( props );
});

// Rotate 360 Degrees 
$(".rotatable").on("mousedown touchstart", function() {
  rotateable = 1;

  if (rotateable) {
    $(".element").each(function() {
      var container = $(this),
          body = $(document),
          angler = container.find(".rotatable").parent();

      angler.on("mousedown touchstart", mouseDown);
      body.on("mouseup touchend", mouseUp);

      function setAngle(value) {
        $("#rotate").val("rotate("+ value +"deg)").change();
      }

      function mouseDown(event) {
        body.on("mousemove.rotatable", handleMove);
        body.on("touchmove.rotatable", handleMove);
        handleMove(event);
        event.preventDefault();
      }

      function mouseUp(event) {
        body.off("mousemove.rotatable", handleMove);
        body.off("touchmove.rotatable", handleMove);
        rotateable = false;
      }

      function handleMove(event) {
        if (rotateable) {
          var mouseX = event.pageX;
          var mouseY = event.pageY;

          setAngle(0);
          var ofs = angler.offset();
          ofs.left += angler.height()/2;
          ofs.top += angler.width()/2;

          var x = mouseX - ofs.left;
          var y = mouseY - ofs.top;

          var angle = Math.atan2(x, y) * 180 / Math.PI;
          angle = 180 - angle;
          // strip decimal, go between 0-360
          angle = ((angle + 360) | 0) % 360;
          setAngle(angle);
        }
      }
    });
  }
});

$(".handlerotate").on('keyup change', function() {
  FinalizeRotation();
  $(".element").css("transform", $("#rotateFinal").val());
});
```